# How to use derived object in list of baseclass for generic extension

Tags: c#, generics, xna, game-engine

Oh boy have I spent a lot of time on this problem...

What I'm trying to do is clone an object of type `GameObject` that also contains a list of `Component`. Cloning `GameObject` types isn't any problem, but it seems this list is a problem as it is cloned but not its content; The content isn't copied but just stored.
As much as I would like to clone these components the same way as I did with the gameobjects, that's not possible because of my system.
Components are attached to a `GameObject` and basically defines the `GameObject`. For example, if I wanted to create a way for the use to control a `GameObject` I would create a Component called something like `PlayerController` that would derive from base type `Component`, looking something like this:

```
class Component
{
    //The gameobject this component is attached to
    public GameObject gameObject { get; set;}

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        //..
    }
}

class PlayerController : Component
{

    override Update()
    {
        Move();
        //..
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The way I'm cloning GameObject is in a method like this:

```
public GameObject Clone(Vector2 position, float scale)
{
    GameObject source = this;
    GameObject clone = new GameObject();
    //Get all properties of a GameObject
    var srcProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(GameObject)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
    //Assign all properties from the source to the clone
    foreach (var srcProperty in srcProperties)
    {
        srcProperty.SetValue(clone, srcProperty.GetValue(source));
    }
    //Clone all components from source and add them to the clone
    if (source.components.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = source.components.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var srcComp = source.components[i];
            var compClone = srcComp.CloneComponent();
            clone.components.Add(compClone);
        }
    }

    clone.position = position;
    clone.scale = scale;
    AllGameObjects.Add(clone);

    if (clone.components.Count > 0)
    {
        //Set the owner gameobjects and start the components
        for (int i = clone.components.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var comp = clone.components[i];
            comp.gameObject = clone;
            comp.Start();
        }
    }

    return clone;
}
```

The `CloneComponent()` method from the 17th line `var compClone = srcComp.CloneComponent();` is a generic extension method that looks like this:

```
public static TComponent CloneComponent<TComponent>(this TComponent source) where TComponent : Component, new()
{
    TComponent clone = new TComponent();

    var srcProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TComponent)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();

    foreach (var srcProperty in srcProperties)
    {
        srcProperty.SetValue(clone, srcProperty.GetValue(source));
    }

    return clone;
}
```

This method works fine, if the source wasn't taken from a list of `Component` as is seems to convert whatever type it was to the root type **which it only does when being used as an argument**. This obviously results in `TComponent` being of type `Component` and instead of cloning the source it just converts it to the root type and only clones properties from that.
What I'm asking for is for a way to bypass this, or for it to not convert to the root type when used as an argument?

**Edit:**
The type of the parameter `source` will be of correct type, however `TComponent` will always be of type `Component` when source argument is given as an argument **from a list**. You might think I'm explaining this incorrect but I think it's just as weird as you do. The only thing I can think of is that it's a bug, which I think is unlikely.

**Final edit:**

Thank you so much @Philipp for the suggestion to use `Activator.CreateInstance`. This is how I changed my `CloneComponent()` method:

```
public static Component CloneComponent(this Component source)
{
    var clone = Activator.CreateInstance(source.GetType());

    var srcProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source.GetType()).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();

    foreach (var srcProperty in srcProperties)
    {
        srcProperty.SetValue(clone, srcProperty.GetValue(source));
    }

    return (Component)clone;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source.GetType()` instead of `typeof(TComponent)` should return the actual (inherited) type and you could create an Instance using `Activator.CreateInstance()`. Also, you could always binary-serialize the entire tree and deserialize again, giving you a complete deep clone of the object graph.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I need to make an edit - The source is of correct type but TComponent is always Component ONLY when the argument is from an list. This means that `clone` is of type `Component`, so if I use `source.GetType()` instead it will give me an error as it will try to assign values to properties that `clone` doesn't have. I'm having a really tough time explaining what's going on here as it seems like a very weird outcome... What's weird is that wherever I call `CloneComponent`, `TComponent` will be correct except if the argument is taken from a list...

Comment: Also binary serialization isn't an option since I'm using the xna framework and can't make types like `Vector2` serializable.

Comment: Though, using Activator.CreateInstance() in `CloneComponent` fixed my problem, thank you so much my good sir and have a wonderful day!